# Insert into new column after line feed

Tags: mysql

I have a basic Insert Into query for copying addresses from one table to another. For the table I'm inserting from, I have a single column called Address, and that needs to insert into Address1 and Address2 of my second table. However, I only want values after any line feeds (\n) in `table1.address` to go into `table2.address2`, and obviously everything before would go into `table2.address1`. Is this possible?

```
INSERT INTO table2.shipin
  (address1,
  address2)
SELECT
  table1.address,
  ''
FROM schema.table1;
```

This is basically what I have right now where everything is going into `table2.address1`.

Comment: LOCATE('\n',address) will return the offset of the first newline, then you should be able to use LEFT and SUBSTRING to break the address up. You may well have to use a CASE statement to differentiate addresses with a newline in from those without.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the suggestion above, I used substring_index to accomplish what I wanted, here is the final solution:

```
Select
substring_index(table1.address, '\n', +1) AS `Address1`,
IF(table1.address REGEXP '\n',
    substring_index(table1.address, '\n', -1),
    '') AS `Address2`,
```

For Address1, this puts anything before a line feed in the column, and for Address2, if there's a line feed in the Address, it will put anything after the feed into Address2, else it will return blank.